# Proof of Cauchy-Riemann equations using differentials as quotients?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

In my analysis 2 book the proof goes like this:

If a complex function $f = P(x,y) + iQ(x,y)$ is differentiable at a point $z$, then

$$
\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \frac{f(z + \Delta z) - f(z)}{\Delta z} = \alpha \in \mathbb{C}
$$

where $\Delta z = \Delta x + i\Delta y$ doesn't depend on the path that it takes to reach zero. That means that it doesnt depend on the argument, and because

$$
tg \ arg  \Delta z = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}
$$

that means that the limit does not depend on the quotient $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$.

Now the part that I'm having trouble with:

Now when we express the derivative using differentials we have
\begin{align}
\alpha = f'(z) &= \frac{df}{dz} = \frac{d(P(x,y) + iQ(x,y))}{d(x + iy)} = \frac{dP + idQ}{dx + idy} = \\
&= \frac{P_xdx + P_ydy + i(Q_xdx + iQ_ydy)}{dx + idy} = \\ 
&= \frac{(P_x + iQ_x)dx + (P_y + iQ_y)dy}{dx + idy} \tag{*}
\end{align}
Independence of the way $\Delta z$ goes to zero implies that the last fraction (*) does not depend on the quotient $\frac{dy}{dx}$. That means that for all $\frac{dy}{dx} = t \in \mathbb{R}$, $ (P_x + iQ_x) + (P_y + iQ_y)t = \alpha + i\alpha t$, which is equivalent to $P_x + iQ_x = \alpha $ and $P_y + iQ_x = i\alpha$, i.e.
$$
P_x = Q_y, P_y = -Q_x
$$

What bothers me is the use of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as a simple quotient, when it denotes a derivative, and also the mixing of differentials of multivalued functions such as $P$ and $Q$ and the differential of $x$ and $y$ which are independent variables.
I don't understand when can I treat derivatives in Leibniz notation as simple quotients and move them around like in this proof.

Comment: I think you mean $\Delta z\rightarrow 0$ in the limit formula

Comment: I admit I have also some problems with notation: I do not like it at all. The proof of "differentiability ---> C.R. equations" can be simplified a lot using a more coherent setting. The (or, maybe "a") problem with derivatives and quotients is that a derivative is a limit, and not a quotient. I suggest you to read the excellent answers in this thread to have an idea on the topic: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-fracdydx-not-a-ratio